# how could I send training data to the node that excutes the command

Tags: deep-learning, cluster-computing, slurm

I am using slurm to manipulate the gpus to train my model. I configured the python environment on node A, which is where my code and data stored. The common practice is like this:

```
srun -p gpu --ntasks-per-node=1 --gres=gpu:2 python train.py
```

This will let slurm find a node for me and run my code on this node. Here I found my code is running 3 times slower than it will run on some local machine with same number of gpus. I guess the reason is that the data used in the code is stored on node A, while slurm assigned a node B for me to run my code. Thus the data on node A will have to be continuously transmitted from node A to node B which slows down the process.

Here my question is: is there a method that I could copy my data to node B so that the code can use the data like in the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `python train.py` part in your command with a  Bash script that first transfers the data and then run `python train.py`.

Even better would be to consider creating a proper submission script and submit it with `sbath` rather than using `srun` on its own:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -p gpu 
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:2

cp /global/directory/data /local/directory/

python train.py
```

You would need to replace the line `cp /global/directory/data /local/directory/` with a proper command to copy the files. It could be `scp` rather than `cp`.